# Exch 2019 - Change display name for the stored mails

Tags: active-directory, exchange

We have the policy to create AD users in format of FAMILY NAME Given name, so my name appeared as BARANYI Peter (btw: this is the standard Hungarian format :) ).
Now the management asked us to change the Display name to Given name FAMILIY NAME, so i appear as Peter BARANYI (like in the rest of the world). But this creates some probelm at the Outlook users. They used view folders with sort by name of the sender, therefore the mails appear in two batches, moreover they are far from each other, in between many other senders.

My question is: can we change somehow the Display name of the sender for all the mails received in the past? This should be done for all of the users...
Any idea how to proceed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in and convenient way to change the display name of the sender for messages that have already been received.

Because the received message is displaying static content, not dynamic.

As a workaround, you can create different folders for different senders, and then use mailbox rules to archive messages from the same email address to the same folder.

Comment: Hope things are going well. I am waiting to see if the above information helps. If there's anything else we can help, feel free to let us know.